# What is the logic for parameter entry order in the initial state field of solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy

The van der Pol equation is:

d'' x/dt'' - mu*(1 - x**2)*dx/dt + x = 0

Since it is second order, it has to be reduced for Scipy's `solve_ivp` to be able to process it. So it gets converted to
dx/dt = v
plus
dv/dt = mu*(1 - x^2)*v - x
A video I have then continues with

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

    def vdp_derivatives(t, y):
        x = y[0]
        v = y[1]
        return [v, mu*(1 - x*x)*v - x] 

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
mu = 1
sol = solve_ivp(fun=vdp_derivatives, t_span=[t[0], t[-1]], y0=[1,0], t_eval=t)
```

and further. My question is about the initial state variable, the 'array-like' one. I do not understand why it was chosen as it was. Flipped order works too, though it offsets the plotted curve by about 1.5 along x. What decides, and what are the constraints? If someone has an answer, preferably extendable to other higher order situations, I would appreciate the info.

Comment: You mean starting with `y0=[0,1]` instead of `[1,0]`.  That just starts the oscillator at different condition.  It's more of a math, ODE issue, than a programming one.  There's a Wiki article about  van der Pol, and probably other online sources.

Comment: `y0` is the vector of initial conditions for the system implemented in `vpd_derivatives`.  In your case, `y0[0]` is `x(0)`, and `y0[1]` is `v(0)`.